# Need help utilizing two classes in one function,

Tags: c++

So basically I created two classes for two vectors and got there norms. How would I approach using both classes to find the distance between both vectors in my main function ? I know I can use the friend function but we have not been taught that in class so I have to use the scope  :: operator and constructor and destructors. I been trying different things but nothing works any ideas ? I am fairly new to c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Vector {

private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

public:
    Vector(float xaxis, float yaxis, float zaxis)
    {
        x = xaxis;
        y = yaxis;
        z = zaxis;
    }

    float getx() { return x; }
    float gety() { return y; }
    float getz() { return z; }

    float normVector()
    {
        float result = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) + pow(z, 2));
        return result;
    }
};

class Vectortwo {

private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

public:
    Vectortwo(float xaxis, float yaxis, float zaxis)
    {
        x = xaxis;
        y = yaxis;
        z = zaxis;
    }

    float getx() { return x; }
    float gety() { return y; }
    float getz() { return z; }

    float normVectortwo()
    {
        float result = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) + pow(z, 2));
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector v(2, 2, 2);
    v.getx();
    v.gety();
    v.getz();

    v.normVector();

    cout << " X axis" << v.getx() << endl;
    cout << " Y axis" << v.gety() << endl;
    cout << " Z axis" << v.getz() << endl;

    cout << " The norm of our first vector " << v.normVector() << endl;

    Vectortwo b(3, 3, 3);
    b.getx();
    b.gety();
    b.getz();

    b.normVectortwo();

    cout << " X axis" << b.getx() << endl;
    cout << " Y axis" << b.gety() << endl;
    cout << " Z axis" << b.getz() << endl;

    cout << " The norm of our first vector " << b.normVectortwo() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also  I know include <iostream> is missing at the tope I do not know why it did not appear

Comment: Why have you implemented *two classes* instead of declaring two *instances* of the same class?

Comment: @Andrew Fixed now. You need to format your text as code (e.g. by selecting it and clickng `{}` symbol on the formatting bar), otherwise text in `<>` is interpreted as HTML tag. Not to mention code is hardly readable without proper formatting.

Comment: FYI, `std::vector<int>`.  You may want to rename to avoid any conflicts.  Maybe "Vector3d"?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Oh okay thanks that really helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know I can use the friend function but we have not been taught that in class [...]

You can always use `getx()`, `gety()` and `getz()` directly to calculate the distance. Since this gets a bit tiresome to write more than once you can write a little function that wraps the calculation:

```
float distance(Vector v1, Vectortwo v2)
{
  return sqrt(
      pow(v1.getx() - v2.getx(), 2)
    + pow(v1.gety() - v2.gety(), 2)
    + pow(v1.getz() - v2.getz(), 2)
  );
}
```

It has to be declared before `main()` (but after `Vector` and `Vectortwo`) and could be used like this:

```
cout << "The distance is " << distance(v, b) << " units." << endl;
```

Since you somehow declared to vector classes `Vector` and `Vectortwo` that are basically identical (apart from the name), you can also just remove `Vectortwo` and use `Vector` for both instances, `v` and `b`. That would simplify the code and both parameters of the `distance()` function could be of type `Vector`.

Comment: I thought I had to use the scope operator to use functions outside the class but this makes sense and helps.

Comment: Yeah I made two classes because I  could not figure out how to declare two objects of the same class and then run a function of distance in the main function so I thought making two classes would help

Comment: You can replace `Vectortwo b(3, 3, 3);` by `Vector b(3, 3, 3);` and instance `b` will also be of type `Vector`.